# How can i copy error from console to file and where to include the code and what will be the code?

Tags: java, eclipse

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.Console;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class logfile 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

try
     {

String[] commands = {"cmd","/c", "dir/p"};

final File outputFile = Paths.get("c://users//sihi//logfile.txt", args).toFile();

final ProcessBuilder pb =new PrrocessBuilder(commands).redirectOutput(outputFile).redirectErrorStream(true);

```
        final Process p = pb.start();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String Error;
            while ((Error = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(Error);
            }
            while ((Error = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(Error);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     } } }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write to a file?

Comment: yes how to write console error into a file with same code.

Comment: what is code to get console error into file?

Comment: You keep asking the same questions over and over it seems; consider applying the "try it and see" method sometimes! Also, why do you ask this question when your previous one was precisely how to redirect stderr to a file (which I have answered and which your code already does)?

Answer (score 0):

You use a `ProcessBuilder` and have already redirected your output to a file:

```
final File outputFile = Paths.get("c://users//sihi//logfile.txt", args).toFile();

final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands)
    .redirectOutput(outputFile).redirectErrorStream(true);
```

Just read from `outputFile`...

Also, you use Java 7, so:

```
for (final String line: Files.readAllLines(yourPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    System.out.println(line);
```

And since this is Java 7, instead of creating a `File` for output, create a `Path` and use `.toFile()`:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("c://users//sihi//logfile.txt", args);

final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands)
    .redirectOutput(path.toFile()).redirectErrorStream(true);

final Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor(); // throws InterruptedException

for (final String line: Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: **Files** means is it keyword or what.

Comment: Nothing of the sort; it is just class java.nio.file.Files